# Running one shot blender rendering in AWS

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

we have web app, which uses blender for rendering.
I would like to know if there is any way to run blender rendering in AWS with instant boot.
Rendering takes about 8 seconds on our server(2core) right now, but it doesn't scale and also is running all the time.
I would like to run it like in AWS Lambda.
I would have image with blender and just tell it what to renders. Then it boots, renders image and then it terminates.
I would like to have it at least at same speed as our server is.But it should spare our money anyway.
Is there a way to do that?